# Materials for a speaker

Tags: speakers, copper

if I have a flat, copper sheet and a magnet,  Can I make a speaker?  Or do I need magnet wire coiled up?

Comment: Insufficient research - question should be closed.

Comment: You can make a speaker from what you describe you have but it neither seems cost effective nor would produce anything that is comparable with those available from a multitude of sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force is related to the strength of the magnetic field, which is proportional to the ampere-turns (that's current multiplied by turns) of a coil in a magnetic field.

If you do not have many **turns** you will need a lot of **amperes** to get the same field. Generally solid-state amplifiers don't have output transformers and are expecting to see a load impedance of some ohms. You could imagine a step-down transformer made with fat wire (or tubing) that could produce hundreds of amperes suitable for single turn voice coil.

You might want to think about the implications of a requirement for fat wire to the single-turn coil for motion and damping of the speaker 'cone'.